# match a list of identifiers to another list using perl

Tags: arrays, perl, foreach

I am stuck on how to loop a list over another list. Perhaps I am not searching for the right words but I am stuck and would appreciate any help on my code.

I went over this thread but am still getting errors running my script. [How do I search a Perl array for a matching string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925604/how-do-i-search-a-perl-array-for-a-matching-string)

the database file

```
chr1    1692239 1692249 AH_GARP2_comp198_c0_seq1
chr1    2233934 2233944 CS_GARP2_comp323_c0_seq1
chr1    5993434 5993444 CS_GARP2_comp635_c0_seq1
chr1    6198157 6198167 CS_GARP2_comp115_c0_seq1
chr1    6465781 6465791 JB_GARP2_comp560_c0_seq1
chr1    7827923 7827933 JB_GARP2_comp855_c0_seq1
chr1    7920939 7920949 AA_GARP2_comp614_c0_seq1
chr1    7964000 7964010 CS_GARP2_comp717_c0_seq1
chr1    9314857 9314867 AH_GARP2_comp237_c0_seq1
chr1    9654532 9654542 AH_GARP2_comp632_c0_seq1
```

the query file

```
name1   CS_GARP2_comp635_c0_seq1
name2   JB_GARP2_comp855_c0_seq1
name3   AH_GARP2_comp198_c0_seq1
name4   AH_GARP2_comp237_c0_seq1
```

My code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl5.16.2
use 5.16.2;
use lib '/users/ec1/perl5/lib/perl5/';
use warnings;
use strict;

my $filename = shift; ## database
my $filename2= shift; ## list of ids
open (DB, '<', $filename ) || die "Unable to open: $!";
open (I , '<', $filename2) || die "Unable to open: $!";

my @DB;

while (<DB>) {
chomp;
my @DB = split /\t/, $_;    ## define as list       
#print "@DB[0,1,2,3]\n";
}       


while (my $line = <I>) {
chomp $line;
my ($name, $id) = split /\t/, $line;

    if ($DB[3] =~ /$id/) {print "$DB[0]\t$DB[1]\t$DB[2]\t$DB[3]\n";
    } else {print "na\n"}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that the `my @DB` inside `while` loop creates a lexical scope so it will always contain the last line's contents and that content will not be available outside the loop.

You should read the id file in to a hash map and check if the line for db file exists as a key in hash.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;

my ($dbfile, $idfile) = @ARGV; 

open my $id_fh, '<', $idfile;
open my $db_fh, '<', $dbfile;

my %ids;

while (<$id_fh>) {
    ++$ids{$_} for (split /\s+/)[1];          # split and put column2 as key in %ids.
}

while (<$db_fh>) {
    my $fld = (split /\s+/)[3];               # split and assign column4 to $fld
    print "na\n" and next unless $ids{$fld};  # print "na" if fld is not in hash and move to next line
    print "$_";                               # print the line if column4 exits. 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So to create the hash it doesn't necessarily need a {key,value} pairing?

Comment: @oolongoni No, `++$ids{$_}` is assigning count as value for each key.

Comment: what if I want to search across the entire line in the database file? This works but i got a warning "Multidimensional syntax $fld[0,3] not supported at hashlookup.pl line 20." `while (<$db_fh>) {my @fld = (split /\s+/); print "na\n" and next unless $ids{$fld[0,3]}; print "$_"; }`

Comment: @oolongoni When you are calling a list, just tell perl so by using `@fld[0,3]` instead. `$` is always scalar.

Answer (score 1):

Put DB into hash (`%DB`) to ease searches.

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $filename = shift; ## database
my $filename2= shift; ## list of ids

my %DB;

open (DB, '<', $filename ) || die "Unable to open: $!";
while (<DB>) {
  chomp;
  my @row = split( /[ \t]+/, $_);    ## define as list  
  die "expected four items in db file - line $.\n" unless @row == 4; # expect four elements in a row
  die "duplicate id in db file - line $." if exists $DB{$row[3]};
  $DB{$row[3]} = \@row;
}
close DB;

open (I , '<', $filename2) || die "Unable to open: $!";
while (<I>) {
  chomp;
  my ($name, $id) = split /[ \t]+/, $_;

  if(exists ($DB{$id})) {
    my @row = @{$DB{$id}};
    print join("\t", @row), "\n";
  } else {
    print "na\n"
  }

}
close(I);
```

P.S. I have changed split pattern to ease tests of copy&paste data file content

Comment: wow! Thank you! I have not learned how to pass reference to arrays before `$DB{$row[3]} = \@row;` I will read more about it

Comment: Slightly more complicated version may even handle data files with multiple rows sharing the same id [hash of arrays of rows instead of hash of rows]