# How to check whether variable is in list?

Tags: list, perl, set

Is there way to do something like this in `perl`?

```
$str = "A"
print "Yes" if $str in ('A','B','C','D');
```

Comment: smartmatch `~~` but it is experimental.

Comment: Is there a way to use an anonymous array or do you have to do what I did in my answer?

Comment: @CJ7: Unrelated but I have noticed that most of the questions you have asked are in open state. Kindly accept the answers for those questions to close them (given that you are satisfied with the answer). Thanks. Also see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I've closed this as a dupe. See Ether's [comprehensive answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2925834/133939)

Answer (score 8):

Smart matching is [experimental](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5180delta.html#The-smartmatch-family-of-features-are-now-experimental) and will change or go away in a future release. You will get warnings for the same in Perl 5.18+ versions. Below are the alternatives:

**Using grep**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $str = "A";
print "Yes" if grep {$_ eq 'A'} qw(A B C D);
```

**Using any**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(any);
print any { $_ eq 'A' } qw(A B C D);
```

**Using hash**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @array = qw(A B C D);
my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } @array;
foreach my $search (qw(A)) #enter list items to be searched here
{
   print exists $hash{$search};
}
```

Also see:

- [**match::smart**](https://metacpan.org/pod/match::smart) - provides a match operator |M| that acts like more or less identically to the (as of Perl 5.18) experimental smart match operator.
- [**Syntax::Feature::Junction**](https://metacpan.org/pod/Syntax::Feature::Junction) - provides keywords for any, all, none, or one
- You may also use [**List::Util::first**](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#first) which is faster as it stops iterating when it finds a match.

Comment: I am using perl v5.16.3 and I don't get any warnings.

Comment: Because it's deprecated in 5.18+ versions.

Comment: List::Util::first and List::Util::any both stop iterating as soon as they find a match, so I'm not sure why you offer `first` as an alternative. `first` also requires you to check for undef if any list elements can be falsy: `say "match" if defined first { ... } @array` vs. simply `say "match" if any { ... } @array`

Answer (score 2):

You can transform your array to a hash. Then you can efficiently (in constant time, or *O*(1)) check if your string was in the original array. Here are two different approaches on how to look for the string `'C'`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash1 = map {$_ => 0} qw/A B C D/;
print 'Yes' if exists $hash1{'C'};
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash2;
@hash2{qw/A B C D/} = ();
print 'Yes' if exists $hash2{'C'};
```

But of course like always in Perl, TIMTOWTDI.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "A";
@arr = ('A','B','C','D');
print "Yes" if $str ~~ @arr;
```

Comment: `print "Yes" if 'A' ~~ ['A','B','C','D'];` works too, but using smartmatch is probably not the best idea.