# Compare two hash of arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have two arrays and a hash holds these arrays

```
 Array 1:
  my $group = "west"
  @{ $my_big_hash{$group} } = (1534,2341,2322,3345,689,3333,4444,5533,3334,5666,6676,3435);

 Array 2 :

   my $element = "Location" ;
   my $group  = "west" ;
   @{ $my_tiny_hash{$element}{$group} } =  (153,333,667,343);
```

Now i would want to compare

> @{ $my_tiny_hash{$element}{$group} }

with

> @{ $my_big_hash{$group} }

and check whether all the elements of tiny hash array are a part of big_hash array .
 As we can see tiny hash has just 3 digit elements and all these elements      are matching with big hash if we just compare the first 3 digits

if first 3 digits/letters match and all are available in the big array, then its matching or We have to print the unmatched elements

Its an array to array comparison.
 How do we achieve it.

PS : Without Array Utils , How to achieve it

The solution using Array Utils is really simple

```
my @minus = array_minus( @{ $my_tiny_hash{$element}{$group} } , @{ $my_big_hash{$group} }  );
```

But it compares all the digits and i would just want to match the first 3 digits

Hope this is clear

Thanks

Comment: As per your edited question. Clarify `match the first 3 digits`.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak "153 of tiny hash " is a part of "1534 of big hash".
Also , its part of the original question , i have just posted the code using Array Utils

Comment: OK, edited answer for the same. I used an temp array which contains first 3 digits of big hash, then used it to compare with tiny.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak : Can we extend the same logic to the one line solution using Array Utils . As i said  this one liner is comapring all the digits and iam interested in just 3

Comment: Yes, see my edited answer. Used the same approach.

Comment: @LearningCpp: Why did you tag this "regex"? There's no regex here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to do what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my (%big_hash, %tiny_hash);
my $group = 'west';
my $element = 'Location';

# Less confusing initialisation!
$big_hash{$group} = [1534,2341,2322,3345,689,3333,4444,5533,3334,5666,6676,3435];
$tiny_hash{$element}{$group} = [153,333,667,343];

# Create a hash where the keys are the first three digits of the numbers
# in the big array. Doesn't matter what the values are.
my %check_hash = map { substr($_, 0, 3) => 1 } @{ $big_hash{$group} };

# grep the small array by checking the elements' existence in %check_hash
my @missing = grep { ! exists $check_hash{$_} } @{ $tiny_hash{$element}{$group} };

say "Missing items: @missing";
```

**Update:** Another solution that seems closer to your original code.

```
my @truncated_big_array = map { substr($_, 0, 3) } @{ $big_hash{$group} };
my @minus = array_minus( @{ $my_tiny_hash{$element}{$group} } , @truncated_big_array );
```

Comment: The logic is identical to yours. Mine's just a bit terser :-)

Comment: Thanks for the solutions.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and bit dirty solution (which extends your existing code).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my (%my_big_hash, %my_tiny_hash, @temp_array);
my $group = "west";
@{ $my_big_hash{$group} } = (1534,343,2341,2322,3345,689,3333,4444,5533,3334,5666,6676,3435);
foreach (@{ $my_big_hash{$group} }){
    push @temp_array, substr $_, 0,3;
}
my $element = "Location";
my $group2  = "west";    
@{ $my_tiny_hash{$element}{$group2} } =  (153,333,667,343,698);


#solution below
my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } @temp_array;
foreach my $search (@{$my_tiny_hash{'Location'}->{west}}){
   if (exists $hash{$search}){
        print "$search exists\n";
   }
   else{
        print "$search does not exist\n";
   }
}
```

Output:

```
153 exists
333 exists
667 exists
343 exists
698 does not exist
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/o5sLLV)

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39585810/257635

---

Edit: As per request using Array::Utils.

```
foreach (@{ $my_big_hash{$group} }){
    push @temp_array, substr $_, 0,3;
}

my @minus = array_minus( @{ $my_tiny_hash{$element}{$group} } , @temp_array  );
print "@minus";
```

Comment: Thanks for the solutions.

Comment: You're welcome. Make sure you post clear question with correct formatting from next time, so that it's easier to understand at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, using ordered comparison instead of hashes:

```
@big = sort (1534,2341,2322,3345,689,3333,4444,5533,3334,5666,6676,3435);
@tiny =  sort (153,333,667,343,698);
for(@tiny){
  shift @big while @big and ($big[0] cmp $_) <0;
  push @{$result{ 
    $_ eq substr($big[0],0,3) 
    ? "found" : "missing" }},
    $_;
}
```

Contents of `%result`:

```
{
      'found' => [
                   153,
                   333,
                   343,
                   667
                 ],
      'missing' => [
                     698
                   ]
}
```