# substring match in perl, yes or no

Tags: perl

With perl, I want to find a substring in a string. The result is a True/False and then I will decide what to do. There is good post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925834/859227), but the usage is vague for me.

```
my $big_string = "Hello Good World";
my $pat = "world";
```

While the capital/non-capital letters are not important, I want to get True.

```
use List::Util 'any';
my $match_found = any { /$pat/ } @big_string;
if (match_found)
   print "yes\n";
else
   print "no\n";
```

Is that correct? Is there any better API for this purpose?

Comment: Your syntax is completely wrong. Have you tried running this code? You are also talking about a single string in your first code block, and suddenly have an array of probably strings in the second.

Comment: I just want to try to write the code. I know it may not be correct.

Comment: Then you should probably try to run it, too. Usually code-writing involves running it. At least for me. ;) And if you don't want to run it, you can still syntax-check it with `perl -c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not correct because it doesn't even compile: `if` / `else` are always followed by a `{` `}` block in Perl. Also, `if (match_found)` is missing the `$` sigil on the variable.

If you really want case insensitive matching (i.e. to ignore the differences between uppercase and lowercase letters), you need to add the `i` flag to the regex.

Finally, your code doesn't define a `@big_string` array, only a `$big_string` scalar.

So:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 'any';

my $big_string = "Hello Good World";
my $pat = "world";

my $match_found = any { /$pat/i } $big_string;
if ($match_found) {
   print "yes\n";
} else {
   print "no\n";
}
```

This code would work, but it can be improved.

First off, why use `any` at all? We don't have a list of multiple strings to check:

```
my $match_found = $big_string =~ /$pat/i;
```

Second, `$pat` doesn't look like it's supposed to be a regex. It's a plain string. This doesn't make any difference for alphanumeric characters (such as `world`), but in general we should escape all regex metacharacters in strings that aren't intended to be interpreted as regexes. This can be done with the `quotemeta` function (or its `\Q` `\E` short form):

```
my $match_found = $big_string =~ /\Q$pat\E/i;
```

This is our improved version:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $big_string = "Hello Good World";
my $pat = "world";

my $match_found = $big_string =~ /\Q$pat\E/i;
if ($match_found) {
   print "yes\n";
} else {
   print "no\n";
}
```

Finally, we don't even need a regex for a simple substring search. Instead we can do this:

```
use feature 'fc';
my $match_found = index(fc($big_string), fc($pat)) >= 0;
```

[`fc`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#fc-EXPR) implements full Unicode case folding.

Comment: And `fc` is only available in 5.16+.

Comment: I think I won't use regex for this work. I want to find a substring match. Both strings are plain text and the pattern is a whole word.

Comment: @simbabque 5.16 has been out for 5 years. I'm OK with that. :-)

Comment: @mahmood your code has a regex pattern match. melpomene is just correcting your bugs. And their last example is a pure substring match. `index` is similar to `substr`, but stops at the first occurance and returns the position, not the string.